# Stretch Glyphicons 100% Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Given a `<div>`, I can put an image inside and say `max-width: 100%` to make it fill the `<div>`.

How can I do this with Glyphicons? I can control it's size with `font-size: ##px` but this will not allow it to re-size as the width of the `<div>` changes.

Comment: can you provide a quick jsfiddle of what you mean?

Comment: did u tried font-size in percentage?

Comment: font-size in percentage does not work.

Comment: 100% would not be of the div, but rather the container. Something like this isn't possible only with CSS, but there are jQuery plugins that accomplish it. Here is a good one: http://fittextjs.com/